# Query for timestampz field with index 3 times slowly then without

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have integration_event table with ~300k db entries in postgres.
Indexes added for:

pk,
committed_date_time (timestamptz) - btree,

response_body(text) + response_business_description(varchar 5000) + response_business_code(varchar100) + response_headers(text) - gin (gin_trgm_ops).

This EF core generated query completed in 10 seconds:

```
SELECT i.committed_date_time AS "CommittedDateTime", i.external_object_id AS "ExternalObjectId", i.external_system AS "ExternalSystem", i.id AS "Id", i.internal_object_id AS "InternalObjectId", i.is_successful_request AS "IsSuccessfulRequest", i.object_type AS "ObjectType", i.request_direction AS "RequestDirection", i.request_http_method AS "RequestHttpMethod", i.request_url AS "RequestUrl", i.response_business_code AS "ResponseBusinessCode", i.response_business_description AS "ResponseBusinessDescription", i.response_http_code AS "ResponseHttpCode", i.task_id AS "TaskId"
FROM events.integration_event AS i
WHERE (i.committed_date_time >= '2021-12-14 03:00:00.000 +0300') AND (((((('00294961' = '') OR
(strpos(lower(i.response_body), '00294961') > 0)) OR (('00294961' = '') OR
(strpos(lower(i.response_business_code), '00294961') > 0))) OR (('00294961' = '') OR
(strpos(lower(i.response_business_description), '00294961') > 0))) OR (('00294961' = '') OR
(strpos(lower(i.response_headers), '00294961') > 0)))
ORDER BY i.committed_date_time DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

In execution plan I see only committed_date_time index using.
If I delete this index, no one used and query completed in ~3 seconds.
If I delete multicolumn index nothing changes.

Explain without any indexes:

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=64058.96..64060.13 rows=10 width=276) (actual time=2810.118..2815.614 rows=0 loops=1) |
| Output: committed_date_time, external_object_id, external_system, id, internal_object_id, is_successful_request, object_type, request_direction, request_http_method, request_url, response_business_code, response_business_description, response_http_code, task_id |
| Buffers: shared hit=113016 read=92539 dirtied=239 written=68 |
| -> Gather Merge (cost=64058.96..79140.58 rows=129262 width=276) (actual time=2810.117..2815.612 rows=0 loops=1) |
| Output: committed_date_time, external_object_id, external_system, id, internal_object_id, is_successful_request, object_type, request_direction, request_http_method, request_url, response_business_code, response_business_description, response_http_code, task_id |
| Workers Planned: 2 |
| Workers Launched: 2 |
| Buffers: shared hit=113016 read=92539 dirtied=239 written=68 |
| -> Sort (cost=63058.94..63220.52 rows=64631 width=276) (actual time=2794.379..2794.380 rows=0 loops=3) |
| Output: committed_date_time, external_object_id, external_system, id, internal_object_id, is_successful_request, object_type, request_direction, request_http_method, request_url, response_business_code, response_business_description, response_http_code, task_id |
| Sort Key: i.committed_date_time DESC |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=113016 read=92539 dirtied=239 written=68 |
| Worker 0: actual time=2786.424..2786.425 rows=0 loops=1 |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=36144 read=30162 dirtied=52 written=13 |
| Worker 1: actual time=2786.908..2786.909 rows=0 loops=1 |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=36415 read=29682 dirtied=77 written=19 |
| -> Parallel Seq Scan on events.integration_event i (cost=0.00..61662.29 rows=64631 width=276) (actual time=2794.338..2794.338 rows=0 loops=3) |
| Output: committed_date_time, external_object_id, external_system, id, internal_object_id, is_successful_request, object_type, request_direction, request_http_method, request_url, response_business_code, response_business_description, response_http_code, task_id |
| Filter: ((i.committed_date_time >= '2021-12-14 03:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) AND ((strpos(lower(i.response_body), '00294961'::text) > 0) OR (strpos(lower((i.response_business_code)::text), '00294961'::text) > 0) OR (strpos(lower((i.response_business_description)::text), '00294961'::text) > 0) OR (strpos(lower(i.response_headers), '00294961'::text) > 0))) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 64464 |
| Buffers: shared hit=112940 read=92539 dirtied=239 written=68 |
| Worker 0: actual time=2786.353..2786.354 rows=0 loops=1 |
| Buffers: shared hit=36106 read=30162 dirtied=52 written=13 |
| Worker 1: actual time=2786.858..2786.858 rows=0 loops=1 |
| Buffers: shared hit=36377 read=29682 dirtied=77 written=19 |
| Planning Time: 0.070 ms |
| Execution Time: 2815.637 ms |

[query plan without indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANliD.png)

With Indexes

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=0.42..15.67 rows=10 width=276) (actual time=7687.437..7687.438 rows=0 loops=1) |
| Output: committed_date_time, external_object_id, external_system, id, internal_object_id, is_successful_request, object_type, request_direction, request_http_method, request_url, response_business_code, response_business_description, response_http_code, task_id |
| Buffers: shared hit=168221 read=152857 |
| -> Index Scan Backward using ix_commited_date_time on events.integration_event i (cost=0.42..236678.30 rows=155194 width=276) (actual time=7687.436..7687.436 rows=0 loops=1) |
| Output: committed_date_time, external_object_id, external_system, id, internal_object_id, is_successful_request, object_type, request_direction, request_http_method, request_url, response_business_code, response_business_description, response_http_code, task_id |
| Index Cond: (i.committed_date_time >= '2021-12-14 03:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) |
| Filter: ((strpos(lower(i.response_body), '00294961'::text) > 0) OR (strpos(lower((i.response_business_code)::text), '00294961'::text) > 0) OR (strpos(lower((i.response_business_description)::text), '00294961'::text) > 0) OR (strpos(lower(i.response_headers), '00294961'::text) > 0)) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 193323 |
| Buffers: shared hit=168221 read=152857 |
| Planning: |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3 |
| Planning Time: 0.142 ms |
| Execution Time: 7687.460 ms |

[query plan with indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9SyA.png)

First question - why its slowly?

Second - why multicolumn index not used?

Third - is there any way to multicolumn gin index includes timestamptz column?

I try another index types for committed_date_time, gin index only for response_body(largest text)

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this query?

Comment: could you update the original question with the queryplan? This is unreadable

Comment: added. Is what you need?

Comment: This is the result from just an explain, without tho other options

Comment: Your list of indexes isn't understandable.  What is a negative gin?  Please present them as formatted text, using actual CREATE statements (or the output of \d), not in some self-invented notation.

Comment: pg_trgm doesn't support strpos().  Try ILIKE instead.